# Optimizar query con match against en 3 tablas. Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, match

Estoy tratando de optimizar esta query ya que me demora 3.7 segundos
También he estado revisando el EXPLAIN y puedo observar la cantidad de filas que recorre que es importante
Pero Mas de ahí no sabría como poder optimizarla.
Si bien se que la cantidad de datos que recorre es "grande" no deberia tener
esta demora la Query. Esta query la hacia antes con like por lo que se podran
imaginar lo larga que era y lo que tardaba.

Le agradeceria alguna sugerencia. Gracias

```
SELECT  e.identificacion,g.serie,g.terminal,g.serie_base,g.tarjeta,g.accesorio_uno,g.accesorio_dos
                     ,g.accesorio_tres,g.accesorio_cuatro,e.emailcliente,e.empresa,
                e.localidad,e.provincia,e.direccion,
                  e.codigo_postal,e.estado,u.name
       FROM 
         equipos e 
         INNER JOIN gestion g 
         ON (g.id_equipo = e.id)
         INNER JOIN users u 
         ON (u.id = g.id_user)
        WHERE 
        g.created_at >= '2021-04-01'
        AND g.created_at <= '2021-04-27%'
        AND g.status_gestion = 'transito'
        and
         ( 
       MATCH (e.identificacion,e.emailcliente,e.empresa,e.localidad,e.provincia,
         e.direccion,e.codigo_postal,e.estado,e.created_at) AGAINST
         ('"*MARIANOD302@GMAIL.COM*"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
        OR 
         MATCH (g.identificacion,g.terminal,g.serie,g.serie_base,g.tarjeta,g.estado,
         g.created_at) AGAINST ('"*correoGMAIL.COM*"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
         OR 
         MATCH (u.name) AGAINST ('"*correo@GMAIL.COM*"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
         )
```

Mis tablas son INNODB

equipos tiene 240.000 filas

gestion 45.000 filas

users 700 filas

[image: He aqui el explain]

Estructura de tablas con sus indices

```
CREATE TABLE `equipos` (
    `id` INT(15) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `id_local` INT(15) NOT NULL,
    `cod_empresa` VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `tipo` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `empresa` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `equipo` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `tarjeta` VARCHAR(80) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `terminal` VARCHAR(80) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `serie` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `temp` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `serie_base` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `idd` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `id_orden` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `id_actividad` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `identificacion` VARCHAR(60) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `nombre_cliente` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `direccion` VARCHAR(250) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `localidad` VARCHAR(150) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `codigo_postal` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `provincia` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `fecha_creacion` VARCHAR(30) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `telefono1` VARCHAR(80) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `telefono2` VARCHAR(80) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `telefono_fijo1` VARCHAR(80) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `telefono_fijo2` VARCHAR(80) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `telefono_fijo3` VARCHAR(80) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `telefono_cel4` VARCHAR(80) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `telefono_cel5` VARCHAR(80) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `telefono_cel6` VARCHAR(80) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `fecha_de_envio` VARCHAR(60) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `cartera` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `baja` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `emailcliente` VARCHAR(150) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `id_user` VARCHAR(150) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `otrosaccesorios` VARCHAR(150) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `id_orden_pass` VARCHAR(150) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `order_rec` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `latitude` VARCHAR(150) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `longitude` VARCHAR(150) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `fecha_ingreso` VARCHAR(150) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `fecha_add` VARCHAR(150) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `fechafirma` VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `motivo_retiro` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `doc_entrega` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `aclaracion_entrega` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `momento` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `estado` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `created_at` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `updated_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
    `search` TEXT(65535) DEFAULT NULL AS (concat(`identificacion`,' ',`emailcliente`,' ',`empresa`,' ',`localidad`,' ',`provincia`,' ',`direccion`,' ',`codigo_postal`,' ',`estado`,' ',`created_at`)) virtual COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
    UNIQUE INDEX `id_local` (`id_local`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `identificacion` (`identificacion`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `tarjeta` (`tarjeta`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `empresa` (`empresa`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `provincia` (`provincia`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `codigo_postal` (`codigo_postal`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `localidad` (`localidad`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `id_orden_pass` (`id_orden_pass`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `serie` (`terminal`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `terminal` (`serie`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `id_user` (`id_user`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `horario_rec` (`created_at`) USING BTREE,
    FULLTEXT INDEX `INDEXEQUIPOS` (`identificacion`, `emailcliente`, `empresa`, `localidad`, `provincia`, `direccion`, `codigo_postal`, `estado`)
)
```

equipo

Estructura de tabla gestion con sus indices

```
 CREATE TABLE `gestion` (
        `id` INT(50) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `id_equipo` INT(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
        `id_orden_pass` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
        `id_orden` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
        `id_user` INT(20) NOT NULL,
        `id_user_update` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
        `identificacion` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
        `terminal` VARCHAR(80) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
        `serie` VARCHAR(70) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
        `serie_base` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
        `tarjeta` VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
        `chip_alternativo` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
        `accesorio_uno` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
        `accesorio_dos` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
        `accesorio_tres` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
        `accesorio_cuatro` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
        `motivo` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
        `fecha_update` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
        `accesorios` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
        `estado` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
        `lat` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
        `lng` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
        `nombre_recolector` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
        `modelo` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
        `created_at` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
        `updated_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
        `status_gestion` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
        `search` TEXT(65535) DEFAULT NULL AS (concat(`identificacion`,' ',`serie`,' ',`terminal`,' ',`tarjeta`,' ',`estado`,' ',`created_at`)) virtual COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
        PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
        INDEX `estado` (`estado`) USING BTREE,
        INDEX `identificacion` (`identificacion`) USING BTREE,
        INDEX `id_local` (`id_equipo`) USING BTREE,
        INDEX `created_at` (`created_at`) USING BTREE,
        INDEX `motivo` (`motivo`) USING BTREE,
        INDEX `terminal` (`terminal`) USING BTREE,
        INDEX `serie` (`serie`) USING BTREE,
        INDEX `id_orden_pass` (`id_orden_pass`) USING BTREE,
        INDEX `id_orden` (`id_orden`) USING BTREE,
        INDEX `status_gestion` (`status_gestion`) USING BTREE,
        FULLTEXT INDEX `INDEX1` (`identificacion`, `terminal`, `serie`, `serie_base`, `tarjeta`, `estado`)
    )
```

estructura de tabla users con sus indices

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user_managent_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `email` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `email_hash` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `password` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `password_hash` VARCHAR(200) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `name` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `surname` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `name_alternative` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `date_of_birth` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `id_number` VARCHAR(30) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `type_document` VARCHAR(15) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `id_expiration_date` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `knowledge_path` TEXT(65535) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `province` TEXT(65535) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `home_address` TEXT(65535) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `postal_code` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `country` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `location` TEXT(65535) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `phone_number` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `brand_of_vehicle` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `vehicle_type` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `vehicle_brand` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `vehicle_model` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `patent` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `year_of_vehicle` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `customer_service_hours` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `monotribute` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `cbu` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `cuit` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `bank` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `account_type` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `type_request` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `role` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `status_process` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `motive` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `description` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `status_notifications` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `status_signed` MEDIUMTEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `status_pass` VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `email_verified_at` MEDIUMTEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `img_document_front` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `img_document_post` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `img_cuil_rut` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `img_monotribute` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `img_home` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `img_person` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `img_commerce` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `img_signed` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `signed_date` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `new_section` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `date_pass` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `created_at` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `updated_at` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
    `search` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL AS (concat(`email`,' ',`name`,' ',`name_alternative`,' ',`id_number`,' ',`province`,' ',`home_address`,' ',`postal_code`,' ',`country`,' ',`location`,' ',`phone_number`,' ',`cbu`,' ',`cuit`,' ',`bank`,' ',`role`,' ',`created_at`)) virtual COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
    UNIQUE INDEX `mail` (`email`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `search` (`search`) USING BTREE,
    FULLTEXT INDEX `IndexParaGestion` (`name`)
)
```

Comment: Falta la definición de las tablas/índices.

Comment: la informacion de la estructura de tablas?

Comment: Si. Para conocer los índices actuales y tal vez proponer alguno(s) nuevo(s).

Comment: y si creas una tabla con una subquery entre las 3 tablas? y le haces el where a esa tabla ayudaría?

Comment: Ya tienes un filtro por fecha `g.created_at >= '2021-04-01' AND g.created_at <= '2021-04-27'` que, sería mejor con esto: `g.created_at BETWEEN '2021-04-01' AND '2021-04-27'`... el caso es, ¿por qué incluir la fecha también en el `MATCH`? Si buscas una fecha fuera de los límites, supongo que, por lo mismo, no se va a encontrar una coincidencia.

Comment: tienes razon. Quite el created_at del indice ful text y mejoro en un 5%. Gracias. Sigo mejorandola. @Triby

Answer (score 1):

Está tomando el índice de estatus, pero al incluir todas las fechas -de ese estado- tiene que comparar una por una para encontrar las que están dentro del rango. Le va a ayudar mucho si le agregas la fecha:

```
ALTER TABLE gestion DROP INDEX status_gestion;
ALTER TABLE gestion ADD INDEX status_gestion (status_gestion,created_at);
```

Y recuerda invertir los predicados conforme al índice:

```
WHERE g.status_gestion = 'transito'
  AND g.created_at BETWEEN '2021-04-01' AND '2021-04-27'
```

Pero sobre todo, cambia `created_at` a `DATE`, que internamente son 3 bytes; es más rápido comparar 3 bytes que 10.

Comment: Es bueno tu aporte, pasa que tambien tengo que hacer match en g.created_at para buscar por fecha

Comment: Saca la fecha del `match` y agrega un `OR`, valdrá la pena ;).

Comment: Lo hice y el rendimiento es el mismo. Gracias bro

Comment: ¿Qué te da el EXPLAIN para `g`?

Comment: explain select * from gestion?

Comment: No, el EXPLAIN de la consulta con los cambios.

Comment: quite el created_at del indice ful text. No puedo colocar date al created_at pq tambien ncesito guardar fecha y hora en ese campo. Ha mejorado en un 5%

Answer (score 0):

Podrías cambiar los MATCH por LOCATES:

```
LOCATE("MARIANOD302@GMAIL.COM",CONCAT(e.identificacion,e.emailcliente,e.empresa,
e.localidad,e.provincia,e.direccion,e.codigo_postal,e.estado,e.created_at))>0
```

y

```
LOCATE("correoGMAIL.COM",CONCAT(g.identificacion,g.terminal,g.serie,g.serie_base,
g.tarjeta,g.estado,g.created_at))>0
```

para mas seguridad podrias usar `CONCAT_WS`

con el ultimo podrías hacer `u.name LIKE "%correo@GMAIL.COM%"`

Comment: Gracias, o sea, usted dice, en vez de usar match against, usar solo locate?

Comment: Si. El tiempo de ejecucion es el mismo que con match against